# Set Same value in two dropdowns by click on checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

I am using Carmen gem for country DropDown. I am using carmen at two places. I want to set these dropdowns equal with selected value by clicking on checkbox.  Html code for drop down:-

```
 <select id="contact_attributes" name="dealer[contact_attributes][country]" class="initialized">
<option value="AF">Afghanistan</option>
<option value="AL">Albania</option>
<option value="IN" selected="selected>India</option>
</select>

 <input type="checkbox" id="SameAsCurrentAddress" class="filled-in">

 <select id="permanent_address" name="dealer[permanent_address_attributes][country]" class="initialized">
 <option value="AF">Afghanistan</option>
 <option value="AL">Albania</option>
 <option value="IN">India</option>
 <option value="US" selected="selected">United States</option
 <option value="AD">Andorra</option>
 <option value="AO">Angola</option>
 </select>
```

My code is here:

```
$('#SameAsCurrentAddress').on('click', function () {
    if ($('#SameAsCurrentAddress').is(':checked')) {
      $('select#permanent_address').val($('select#contact_attributes').val());
});
```

But i am unable to set the value eqaul. How to set equal? Please help me.

Comment: Where is the HTML code from the dropdowns and the checkbox?

Comment: I already added. Please check question again

Comment: Well, you don't have any `select` elements in your HTML code, so your javascript will not have an effect.  If you want to synchronize the `input` elements, give them each an id, and do: `$('#input2').val($('#input1').val());`

Comment: Sorry for mistake. i again modified question. Please go through this

Comment: You are missing a quote mark here: `<option value="IN" selected="selected>India</option>`

Comment: You are also missing a close carat here: `<option value="US" selected="selected">United States</option`

Comment: You are also missing a `}` in your javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a bunch of syntax errors.  Please use a good IDE like Eclipse to catch these errors for you.  This works:

```html
 <select id="contact_attributes" name="dealer[contact_attributes][country]" class="initialized">
<option value="AF">Afghanistan</option>
<option value="AL">Albania</option>
<option value="IN" selected="selected">India</option>
</select>

 <input type="checkbox" id="SameAsCurrentAddress" class="filled-in">

 <select id="permanent_address" name="dealer[permanent_address_attributes][country]" class="initialized">
 <option value="AF">Afghanistan</option>
 <option value="AL">Albania</option>
 <option value="DZ">Algeria</option>
     <option value="US" selected="selected">United States</option>
 <option value="AD">Andorra</option>
 <option value="AO">Angola</option>
 </select>
```

```
$('#SameAsCurrentAddress').click(function () {
    if ($('#SameAsCurrentAddress').is(':checked')) {
      $('#permanent_address').val($('#contact_attributes').val());
    }
});
```

Comment: Works for me http://jsfiddle.net/pnox1e4f/ .  Keep in mind that the value will only sync if both options exist in the selects.  For example, India is only in the first select, not the second.  If you want this to sync, you have to first add another option to the 2nd select.

Comment: I saw you just changed the code in your original post so that India is now in both selects.  That's very dishonest and makes me look like an idiot.